# Not able to push changes to github

Tags: git, github

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to push changes to my repo . It worked fine until 2-3 days ago , Something happened suddenly.

```
unable to access 'https://github.com/meetmangukiya/meetmangukiya.github.io/': error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_25d850739bc178b2eb13c3e2a9faafea2f9143c0\mingw32/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

Comment: this is a problem in your system, not with github. Try to use https://git-scm.com/download/win original git for windows software. I prefer using ssh connections (git:// URLs) with github.

Comment: @ikrabbe will this affect my existing gits? Should I remove github first .. Will it crash if i dont ?

Comment: no. git and github should work with any git solution you use. Your problem is not git but the implementation of https in your git client and possibly some wrong CA files and certificates. Also check `git config`.

Comment: @ikrabbe thanks! that solved it  :D .. Would you like to write it as an answer or should i just write it as your comment says ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since my comments solved the problem and someone else might stumble above the same system dependencies I copied my comments into an answer:

This is a problem in your system, not with github. Try to use git-scm.com/download/win original git for windows software. I prefer using ssh connections (git:// URLs) with github.

Git and github should work with any git solution you use. Your problem is not git but the implementation of https in your git client and possibly some wrong CA files and certificates. Also check `git config`.

BTW: There are so many git clones and frontends out there, but in the end, the git-scm.com implementation, or the basic git implementation is all you need and in 99% of the cases it solves your problems much better than all these shiny frontends out there, in the wild.